# How to go back to world overview in So Many Me?

Tags: so-many-me

I've started playing So Many me. I'm just past the first boss, and explored the "Worlds Overview" a little bit, then I accidentally entered the string of levels I had already completed.

From such a level, how can I exit it and go back to the levels overview?

All I see is options to:

- Restart Level
- Exit Game (which quits the entire game, not the level)
- "x10 Globe" where I can pick a level in my current world

[image: menu]

The closest workaround I found is going to the last level of the current world with the "X10 Globe" option, and then finish that to go back here:

[image: world overview]

The fact that such a workaround is possible makes me feel it should also be possible to just go back immediately? I think I've tried nearly every button on my XBox 360 controller (I'm on PC, if that matters), but didn't find anything.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, once you enter the second world, you get a little tip in your screen that says something like this (from memory):

> You can now visit "Horizon Ruin" from the x10 Globe

So basically: don't re-enter the first world before you've visited other worlds, so that you do have the option to go back to the world overview from the menu.

[image: menu with new option]